# What does the function "par" do in R?

Tags: r, par

I am reading R code for k-mean clustering. The first 3 lines of code are:

```
def.par <- par(no.readonly = T)
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
par(oma = c( 5, 0, 3, 0))
```

I read the help manual, but I am still confused. I assumed that it is important for graphics.

Comment: Have you tried `?par` ??

Comment: `mfrow` controls the number of rows and columns in a multiple plot, while `oma` is used to adjust the outer margins

Comment: It sets the plotting `par`ameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`par` sets the global state for any graphical related commands.

This frees commands like `ggplot`, `plot`, etc from having to store this info on their own.

it also allows the user to swap out graphing methods, ie move from plot to `ggplot2` when they need more power without having to reenter this information again.

In the specific instance you use, `mfrow` tells the app to layout 1 row with 3 columns

`oma` is used to set an outer margin on the drawing surface.

As always, help(....) and ?.... as well as experimentation are your friend when you encounter an R command you don't understand!